# Python 2.6 Django MYSQLDB error

Tags: python, django

Getting started with Django 1.3.1 and Upon running

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

with Python 2.6. I keep getting an `error loading mysqldb module: No module named mysqldb` message. I have tried doing sudo yum install python-mysql and sudo yum install python-mysqldb

on a CentOS 5 system but I get a "no package found" message and the error persists in django.

What's the fix for this?
I would like to keep the Python version as 2.6 to preserve other dependencies so reinstalling 2.5 or something is out of the question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no point using the system packaging tools if you're using a different Python version to the one provided by the system. You'll have to use the Python packaging tools instead - eg `easy_install mysqldb`.

Comment: easy_install doesn't work...but marked as answer because of caveat about using system packaging tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just getting started with Django you should really take a look at [`virtualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and [`pip`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/1.0.1).

This article gives a good overview: http://www.clemesha.org/blog/modern-python-hacker-tools-virtualenv-fabric-pip

You can even [specify the python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv) for your virtual python environments.

And last but not least a good guide on how to get mysql running with virtualenv: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/02/install-mysqldb-virtualenv-ubuntu-karmic/